# RavenDB nested collection lucene query property miss-match

Tags: ravendb

I have ran into a problem I can't figure out and thought i'd ask the experts.
I have a class "SingleDogOwner" and a class and property "Dog".
When I save an instance of SingleDogOwner to RavenDB I have the following in the data store:

```
{
  "Name": "Steve",
  "__CollectionName": "SingleDogOwner",
  "Id": "ExpandoObjects/12929",
  "Dog": [
    {
      "Id": "ExpandoObjects/12929/DOG1",
      "Name": "Fluffy",
      "Breed": "Dalmation",
      "Age": 10,
      "BirthDay": "2005-10-05T00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

If i run this lucene query i get no results:

```
Dog,Name:Fluffy
```

If, however, I change the name of the properties to Dogs, then the following query works perfectly:

```
Dogs,Name:Fluffy
```

It seems that because both items have a "Name" property it doesn't know how to resolve the query unless the name of the property ends with an 's'. In both cases, I can successfully query using the other properties of Dog/Dogs.

Eg,

```
Dog,Breed:Dalmation
```

Works perfectly fine

Any clues as to why this is not working would be much appreciated.

Comment: It has little to do with how your document is defined, and everything to do with how your *index* is defined, which you did not show here.  Please show enough code to reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do a dynamic query, i don't specify an index.

Comment: Just experimenting with dynamic query, I found that the existing indexes (auto or otherwise) could interfere sometimes.  Try seeing if you have an existing index that has `Dogs_Name` defined in the map.  Just a suggestion.